# create a GET request with RequestSpecBuilder

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I have tried query Params and path Params but it is giving error `Undefined path parameters are: job_id`

I guess it is because because URI is ending up in wrong format.

```
builder.addQueryParams(queryParams);
return getAPIResponse();
```

Expected Format is `https://api.themoviedb.org/4/list/{job_id}`

Actual Format is `https://api.themoviedb.org/4/list/?job_id={job_id}`

How can build the URI in expected format?

Comment: Where does `RequestSpecBuilder` belong to? how you construct your object? even if we might guess, we shouldn't be looking it up.. better to provide better snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected is a pathparam `https://api.themoviedb.org/4/list/{job_id}` but you are adding it as a queryParam `addQueryParams`

```
    RequestSpecBuilder builder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
    builder.addPathParam("job_id", "abc");
    RequestSpecification requestSpec = builder.build();

    given().log().all().spec(requestSpec).when().get("https://api.themoviedb.org/4/list/{job_id}");
```